# Switch CSS Style condition by enter a Number in a Textfield (Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, clock

I absolutely need help from some smart people in this community!

I have created an analog clock in HTML and CSS and now want to make the hands of the clock movable using an input mask.

**As an an example:**

I enter the number 11 into the input mask for the hours. (11 pm). The CSS class ".hourhand" should now adjust the rotation accordingly (-30 degrees). Same for 1-12 with different rotation settings.

I have now worked with a lot of Javascripts for three days but never got a round result ...
The code should also be as clean as possible. Maybe via if & else? I'm just an absolute javascript beginner ...

Many Thanks for your help!

Comment: please referece this code.
https://github.com/dgray0229/javascript-analog-clock

Comment: It would help us to help you if you'd share some working code example: [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The position of the hand in degrees rotated can be established by noticing that for 0 hours or 12 hours the degrees is 0 and the amounts for the values in between are:

`(hours / 12) * 360 degrees`

You may want to check that the user inputs a value between 0 and 12 - this snippet simplifies things and just takes the value input mod 12:

```js
const hourhand = document.querySelector('.hourhand');
const update = document.querySelector('.update');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

update.addEventListener('click', function () {
  hourhand.style.setProperty('--degrees', (input.value%12 / 12) * 360);
});
```

```css
.hourhand {
  --degrees: 0; /* this will get changed with Javascript */
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--degrees) * 1deg));
  transform-origin: 50% 100%; /* the bottom of the hour hand */ 
  
  position: relative;
  left: 10vmin;
  rtop: 10vmin;
  width: 1vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5vmin;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="number"/>
<button class="update">Click me to update the hand</button>
<div class="hourhand"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are awesome!!!!

It works fine. But now I have made a stupid mistake in thinking. If I add a minute hand, the hour would have to acquire the appropriate angle of rotation. In other words, at 1:30 p.m. the hour display should be between 1:00 p.m. and 2:00 p.m. ... How do I enter this in the appropriate .style.setProperty?

I already thank you very much!